# Compare object fields of different classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have two objects, each of which have tens of fields:

```
Class1 {
    int firstProperty;
    String secondProperty;
    ...
}

Class2 {
    int propertyOne;
    String propertyTwo;
    ...
}
```

Although the some field are different in name, but they should have same meaning and purpose, for example `firstProperty` and `propertyOne`. I want to compare if the "similar" fields of objects of the two class actually have same values.
What is the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: because you have one object of each class ? share more code

Comment: Do you want to know if they are all the same or do you want to know which one is different?

Comment: You should have `Class1` & `Class2` implement some kind of common interface exposing a getter method for these properties and compare that interface

Comment: @JeremyGrand that's exactly my approach below

Comment: I think I'm going to use this as an interview question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two classes with fields that have similar meanings, I'd consider declaring an `interface`.

```
Class1 implements MyInterface {
    int firstProperty;
    String secondProperty;
    ...
    int getOne() {
        return firstProperty;
    }
    String getTwo() {
        return secondProperty;
    }

}

Class2 implements MyInterface {
    int propertyOne;
    String propertyTwo;
    ...
    int getOne() {
        return propertyOne;
    }
    String getTwo() {
        return propertyTwo;

    ...


}
```

And an `interface` with default implementation of `isEqualTo`:

```
MyInterface {
    int getOne();
    String getTwo();
    ...

    boolean isEqualTo(MyInterface that) {
        return that != null &&
            this.getOne() == that.getOne() &&
            this.getTwo().equals(that.getTwo()) && //add null checks!

            ...;
    }
}
```

There is a risk of `isEqualTo` being overridden - make sure it never happens.

Comment: Assuming that the OP can't really break up his existing classes, this would be a clean way to solve his problem ;-)

Comment: Great solution. I Like it.

Comment: I agree with that solution. To complete it a bit : in the case where the coder does not own one (or both) of the classe, you can write a wrapper implementing `MyInterface` for the 3rd party class.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking how to deal with the symptom of the disease - I would suggest to cure the root cause instead: by stepping back and refactor your classes completely.

A class that has "tens" of fields is most likely violating the **single responsibility principle**.

Don't ask yourself how to compare fields - ask yourself how you could design more classes with less fields that actually **avoid** having the same information in more than one place! You should (almost) always prefer a complex network of simple classes over a simple network of complex classes. Because the *class* is the root of your abstractions, and each class should *only* contain what is required to implement the *one* thing that class is about.

Beyond that: there is no simple generic way that is also *nice*. You can of course write a utility class that compares objects using reflection - you simply give variable names and that utility code does generic comparisons. But is simple and generic - but not *nice*.

Comment: In real life, it is not always possible. For instance, you might encounter situations where you can not reuse the class you want due to the circular dependency of libraries. Or, you have upstream and downstream services that operate on independent contracts and are offered by different vendors and they won't accept any "common class" from you.  

Nowadays is the world of distributed systems while your advice can be most easy implemented in some kind of monolyth.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing objects of different classes by specific fields is exactly the scenario that **https://github.com/nejckorasa/compare-utils** solves.

Example:

```
ObjectCmp.equalEqualityPairs(
    object1,
    object2,
    Arrays.asList(
        EqualityPair.of(o1 -> o1.getFirstProperty(), o2 -> o2.getPropertyOne()),
        EqualityPair.of(o1 -> o1.getSecondProperty(), o2 -> o2.getPropertyTwo())));
```

Take a look, it might be useful!